# Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.11.0-40-generic does not recognize intel wi-fi 6E ax210 160mhz

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, lts, iwlwifi

```
$ uname -r
5.11.0-40-generic
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Thinkpad p14s, and bluetooth works. From what I can tell, the wifi should "just work" for this kernel version, so not sure what i'm missing. Also, the wifi worked before a recent ubuntu update I installed. I reinstalled ubuntu but it's still not working.

Another weird thing, I am using ethernet (because no wifi), but it is 20x to 30x slower than the same ethernet connection when booted in Windows. **UPDATE:** toggling bluetooth fixed this??

- I've disabled fast boot
- I've disabled secure boot

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
...
[    3.503770] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: ethernet speed seems to come back if I disable bluetooth. still no wifi though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've restored wifi functionality. The solution found in this this email thread worked:

https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg209307.html

As per that email, removing this file and rebooting restored wifi functionality:

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

This bug report gives from March gives some context: https://bugs.gentoo.org/777324