# Wifi driver not detected after update Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, iwlwifi

After updating my Ubunut 20.04, my wifi driver is no longer detected. Previously, this was an issue upon initial install and subsequent updates, but
`sudo rm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm`
provided an instant fix as described here: [Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.11.0-40-generic does not recognize intel wi-fi 6E ax210 160mhz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375562/ubuntu-20-04-with-kernel-5-11-0-40-generic-does-not-recognize-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax2).
However, it appears that this file no longer exists, so this fix no longer works. Reinstalling the driver also seems to have not helped.

Edit: See here https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Gchqxh7rQ8/ for the output based on this post: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180).
Interestingly, upon running `sudo apt update`, the faulty file mentioned above reappeared, but removing it did not resolve anything.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: Here's the output from running that: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zdhqgyxPGZ/

Comment: I've tried a few fixes that have failed, so here's the updated output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Gchqxh7rQ8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took over a month, but I've finally found a solution. The fix `sudo rm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` outlined in the above linked post only works for the version `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59` of the firmware and not any newer version, i.e. installing the files associated with version 59 from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/) and deleting all others is what worked for me.

Comment: Interestingly, Intel told me to install the newest version (not even compatible with my machine) which likely delayed my finding this fix by a couple weeks.